# Centering colored lettered text using classes in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the colors of each letter in a sentence using html and css. I have done some research and found this:

For html and css i wrote this:

```css
.green {
  Font-size: 20px;
  Color: #0F3;
  Text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a class=green> H </a>
```

Now it works fine but for some reason the text wont center even though the css code is right. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can only centre block-level elements.

### Why?

Imagine you had normal text, `text-align:left;` next to your `.green` `a` tag, which is `text-align:center;`. How is this going to work?

Thus, an element needs to be displayed as a **block level** element to be centred.

### How?

Include a `display:block` rule in your `.green` style and it should work:

```css
.green {
font-size:20px;
color:#0F3;
text-align:center;
display:block;
}
```

```html
<a class="green">H</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but now each letter is on a seperate line whereas before i added that code the whole sentebce was on one line in different text color

Comment: Ah. In this case, remove the `text-align:center` and `display:block` from `.green` (and your other colours), an then add a parent element (i.e. `<div clsss="colors"></div>`) around all of your letters. In the CSS, set `.colors{text-align:center;}`. Now it should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The parent element should be centering the text!

```
<p style="text-align: center">
    <span class="color">....</span>
    <span class="color">....</span>
    <span class="color">....</span>
    ...
</p>
```